# Can't make this fraction

Tags: fractions

I want to create a formula for summing an arithmetic sequence in which the first term is 'a1' and the nth term is 'an' through the following formula.

```
${{S_n}}$ = \frac{n(${{a_1}}$+${{a_n}}$)}{2}
```

However, the result is as follows.

[image]

How could I solve this problem?
I am currently working on overleaf.

I'm worried that since my native language is not English and I am new to LaTeX, my question may seem a bit odd.

Comment: `$S_n = \frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$` is the correct input. See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. To typeset mathematical expressions, don't enter and leave "math mode" for each symbol. `$` at the beginning and again at the end. Also, you don't need so many braces: `$S_n = \frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$`

Comment: Welcome. // The problem seems to be that you switch the math mode on and off several times. In running text you type $ formulas $, i.e. just 2 $, just like opening and closing braces. Or for longer equation you start math mode by \[ and end it by \] . See related links to the right for examples.

Comment: A different issue: Your description of the summation sounds more to me like `$S_n = \frac{n(a_1 + \ldots + a_n)}{2}$` with an ellipsis representing a₂, a₃, etc., but I might be misunderstanding.

Comment: @frabjous `$S_n = a_1+\dots+a_n = n(a_1+a_n)/2$`.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yeah I should have thought of that … I've even done that inductive proof.

Answer (score 1):

your code has a lot of unnecessary "{..}"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
S_{n}= \frac{n(a_1 + a_n)}{2} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: dont use `$$` in latex

Comment: if we shouldn't use it, why was the $$...$$ placed in latex?

Comment: it is not placed in latex it is a tex primitive that is unfortunately hard to remove, but has never been supported latex syntax. It is not even mentioned in the latex book. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854#69854